# assign a dropdownListfor to an "All" option with value=0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

i have a dropdownList for in my view to which i want to assign an All option with value 0 Suppose

```
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">Account A</option>
<option value="2">Account B</option>
```

And so on , if user dont select any one option by default its selected value should be 0 All.. what i have tried is not working.

here is my code any help will be appreciated.

```
public class ReportViewModel
    {
        public SelectList Account { get; set; }
        public string SelectedAccount { get; set; }

        public SelectList User { get; set; }
        public string SelectedUser { get; set; }
public SelectList Team { get; set; }
        public string SelectedTeam { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAccount, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Account, " ALL ", new { @class = "form-control" })

 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTeam, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Team, " ALL ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller

```
reportViewModel.Account = new SelectList(preFlightDbContext.Accounts.Where(o => o.AccountId != 0 && o.Deleted == false), "AccountId", "AccountName");
reportViewModel.Team = new SelectList(preFlightDbContext.Teams.Where(o => o.TeamId != 0 && o.Deleted == false), "TeamId", "TeamName");
```

Comment: Adding the 3rd parameter `"ALL"` to `DropDownListFor()` will give the option the default null value. You need to generate a `List<SelectListItem>` in you controller rather than `SelectList` (manually add a `SelectListItem` with `Value="0"` and `Text="ALL"`)

Comment: because of having a huge amount of Team based on this model , how can i add this manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to construct `List<SelectListItem>` in the controller and add a `SelectListItem` with the text and value you want. Change your property to

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Account { get; set; }
```

and in the controller

```
List<SelectListItem> accounts = preFlightDbContext.Accounts
    .Where(o => o.AccountId != 0 && o.Deleted == false)
    .Select(o => new SelectListItem()
    {
      Value = AccountId.ToString(), // assumes AccountId is not a string
      Text = AccountName
    }).ToList();
accounts.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "All" });
reportViewModel.Account = accounts;
```

then in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAccount, Model.Account, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

(ditto for `Team`)

Comment: Thats Fine but having a problem with this when the form is submitted, its selected value is not All it is showing the first Account Name, and even the All is not listed in the dopdown

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. If you select `All` in the dropdown, a value of `"0"` will be posted back